# VSCode Python Debugger: Run a shell script in the SAME console as the debug BEFORE the python

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, debugging

I am trying to debug a python program.

When not using VSCode, I open a terminal and then source a setup file that activates the proper conda environment and sets a bunch of environment variables.  This file is provided with my code when I pull from the main devs who write it.

I attempted to add this sourcing comment to a preLaunchTask.  That runs, but it appears to run PRIOR to the establishment of the console the debugger is running in.

So the first time I run it, I get errors because the console is established AFTER the sourcing has run (apparently in a different, and then closed console).  However, if I then manually source the file in that console, the environment is set up correctly and I can hit the debugger arrow to my heart's content.

**So apparently "preLaunch" is not what I want, but some way to run the source shell command task AFTER the console is opened, but before the "program" is executed.**

Is this possible?

Comment: You can achieve this by using a shell script, for example `run.sh` and add `"program": "${workspaceFolder}/run.sh",` to your `launch.json`. It will debug the Python process that the script starts.

Comment: Does that work with the "type": "debugpy" setting in launch.json?

or do I need to enter the debugging command (that pops up in the terminal) to the shell script?

Comment: Yes, you could try it. `"type":"python"` will be deprecated soon.